# Anylogic - Error when drawing animation frame with custom GIS routes

Tags: anylogic

I am using a GIS map for a waterway transportation system and have to use my own GIS Route (not automatically generated). I use the moveTo block but each time the agent arrives at the GIS Point I get an error message saying:

```
"Error while drawing animation frame. Possibly caused by dynamic properties of animation shapes. The picture will be restored when (and if) the error goes away."
```

The following message appears in the console:

```
Error during drawing animation frame:
java.lang.RuntimeException: root:
gisRoute8 (GISRoute) : Offset (9539.429153529953) is greater than length (687.4357796935112)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISMarkupElement.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISRoute$1.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractCurve.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractCurve.getPositionAtOffset(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISRoute.getPositionAtOffset(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.SimpleDirection$2.getPositionAtOffset(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.getPosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.getPositionAtOffset(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractNetwork.getPositionAtOffset(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.b.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ih.updatePosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExtAgentWithSpatialMetricsDelegate.updatePosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.l.updatePosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.h(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.getX(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ih.getLat(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeEmbeddedObjectPresentation.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeAgentGroup_xjal.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.updateShapeDynamicProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameProducer.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.l(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameCollector.l(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameCollector.c(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This happens everytime an agent arrives at a GIS Point from a custom made GIS Route, while automatically generated GIS Routes work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in AnyLogic 8.7.2 when using custom-GIS-routes: the default setting for the GIS Map to get routes from an OSM server conflicts with agents which are using a custom GIS Network for routing. (Confirmed with AnyLogic support and due for fix in 8.7.3.)

If you are *only* using custom GIS Routes, you can workaround this by setting the GIS Map (Routing section) so that routes are *Straight lines* (so that no routing servers are used).

(The error message is stating that it somehow thinks the target point (or some intermediate point en-route) is beyond the extent of the GIS Route network. Initially they are just 'temporary' animation errors but, if you attempt to do a subsequent movement, you get a hard error --- so it seems like the agent has somehow been positioned in a point beyond the confines of the GIS network.)

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot! I ended up using one GIS point for each "turn" and used straight moveTo blocks for each as a temporary fix. I will wait for the update and then try the old method then!

Comment: If you're only using custom GIS Routes, you can fix this now as specified without waiting for 8.7.3.